# Do something on/off your to do list

Tags: prepositions

I'm not sure about the right prepostion for this sentence:

> Do something *on*|*off* your To-Do list.

As in, do any of the things that you have on your To-Do list.
Is *on* correct because it's an item on the list?
Or *off* since you are taking something to do off the list?

Which preposition is correct, or are both possible? If so, which would sound more natural?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"I'll take it off the list (once it is completed)".

"I will do something on the list." is everyday usage and speaks to intention. You could also say, "I will do something from/off the list." You will be perfectly well understood.

"I will do something from off of the list", would work as well.

If I were to talk about what I am doing now: "I am doing this task from the list." "I am doing a job on the (honey-do) list", just sounds a bit awkward but I've heard it.